# How to not have an image in a facebook share

Tags: media, meta-tags

I have a problem

Although many have the problem with not have the right image, I'm trying to have no image at all. I have ads on the page that get chosen because the content type has no image.

I have tried to do put in a "[none]", (then a random field from another content type), in the image field under open graph in meta tags, it's still not working.

I simply want to share the text itself without the image of the ads, and if you have a better solution, please mention.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try investigating URL you are sharing on Facebook Debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

If you are not providing `og:image` meta tag, Facebook will try to get the best matching one, I guess those AD images in your case.

Unfortunately there is no way you could not provide an image, you could try with empty `og:image` meta tag, but I don't think this would work.

It would be best if you provide an image anyway. Here are some hints:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#images

Comment: I have tried all that you have suggested, but it still doesn't work. I have also learned that empty 'code'og'code' tags don't work, leaving nothing for me to do? The content type is meant to be a little announcement with no images. If I recieve no other replies in the near future, I will give you the "best answer" still. Thanks!